# How do I change Whatsapp tones to my own not from the Whatsapp predefined ones

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I want to change it to one that I downloaded off the internet but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Open WhatsApp > Settings > Notifications

Answer (score 0):

Put all your tones in InternalStorage/Notifications or InternalStorage/Ringtones. You'll now find them in ringtone list like **esQmo** said in the comment above (WhatsApp > Settings > Notifications). This works for all messenger apps.